# Is it possible to edit partition on disk image?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ddrescue

I am attempting to recover a crashed 2TB drive using ddrescue. It's been running for over a week now, and just got near the end and apparently ran out of space with this error:

`ddrescue: write error: No space left on device`

It was a blank 2TB drive I was copying to, so am guessing there was a variation in actual drive space from one manufacturer to the next. The drive was not full, only about 600GB used when it crashed, and there were only 20 errors totalling 254MB, so guessing I actually have the vast majority of the data that was on there in the recovered disk image.

When I try and mount the image using this command:

`sudo mount -o loop,ro,offset=0 rimage /mnt/resc`

it fails, and this is showing in the dmesg:

`[999150.073373] EXT4-fs (loop0): bad geometry: block count 488378646 exceeds size of device (480723271 blocks)`

1) Is there a way to edit the block count of the image so that I can mount it?

2) If so, is it possible to then shrink the partition size of the disk image afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

#### Disk Space Issue

Your recovery destination probably ran out of disk space because you were writing to an image file on a filesystem on the destination, and the filesystem has an overhead.  You *might* have been able to get away with the disk space issue with the `--sparse` flag in `ddrescue`.

**I strongly recommend trying to create another image**, avoiding the space issue this time with either a larger hard drive or by using `ddrescue --sparse`.

You can actually use `ddrescue` to write over the whole recovery destination hard drive, skipping a filesystem.  If the recovery destination hard drive is `/dev/sdc`, you would tell `ddrescue` to write to that instead of to `rimage`.  The recovery destination hard drive would then behave like a clone of the failed hard drive, minus the unrecoverable parts.

#### Resizing a Device Image

If the `ddrescue` image is supposed to be of the entire failed drive, run this command, replacing `/dev/sdb` with the device path of the failed drive:

```
sudo blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sdb
```

Take the output (e.g. `500107862016`) and resize your recovery image `/path/to/rimage` using `truncate`:

```
truncate -s 500107862016 /path/to/rimage
```

> **CAUTION:** Truncating to a size less that the size of `/path/to/rimage` **will** result in data loss.
>
> Make sure to check the current size of `/path/to/rimage` with `du -b --apparent-size /path/to/image` and confirm that the size returned is less than what `blockdev` gave you.

Now, the recovered image will take on the full size that `mount.ext4` might be expecting.

#### Resizing a Partition Image

If you were running `ddrescue` on a partition in the failed drive, use this command instead to get the size of the partition, replacing `/dev/sdb1` with the device path of the partition:

```
sudo blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sdb1
```

Then take the output (e.g. `500106788864`) and resize your recovery image `/path/to/rimage` using `truncate`:

```
truncate -s 500106788864 /path/to/rimage
```

> **CAUTION:** Truncating to a size less that the size of `/path/to/rimage` **will** result in data loss.
>
> Make sure to check the current size of `/path/to/rimage` with `du -b --apparent-size /path/to/image` and confirm that the size returned is less than what `blockdev` gave you.

Comment: Thank you, using truncate I was able to get in and can now successfully mount the image, and I can see the data there (although some did definitely fail as I cannot delete some items, I get a r/w error). 

My question about resizing the partition wasn't about resizing the size of an image that was of a partition, it's is there a way using parted or some other tool to shrink the partition on the image itself, thus allowing me to move the data from the image onto the drive, without needing a 3rd drive. Re-running ddrescue for another week is very unappealing.

Comment: @MichaelVanDeMar: What you propose risks data loss because the filesystem cannot guarantee integrity upon resizing, especially with holes in the data.  If your data are important to you, you should try to preserve every single bit until you're sure you got everything you can get.  (It sounds like you've modified the image already, though.)  **I do not recommend attempting to resize the recovered data.**

Comment: I can't copy it over though until I shrink it, as it is currently occupying the entire disk. Is there a way to use parted or gparted, or some other disk utility, to shrink the partition on the image? When mounted, if I use Fedora's Disks utility the option to edit the partition is grayed out, and I don't know how to point that at an unmounted image.

Worse case scenario, if something glitches and I absolutely had to, I could always start over either using --sparse as you suggested, or writing to the disk itself instead of to an image.

Comment: @MichaelVanDeMar: In short, no, because the filesystem is in charge of the resize, but corrupted data means that the filesystem can't be trusted on its own.  As a result, I stress that you need to preserve as much of the original data as you can.  If you can spare an external hard drive, `qemu-img convert -O qcow2 -cp /path/to/rimage /path/to/exthdd/rimage.qcow2` might offer significant space savings while preserving all data.  If you can't, you may have to resort to `fsck`ing the partition inside `/path/to/rimage`.